# Extjs make west panel expanding over the center panel

Tags: layout, extjs

I have this border layout: http://jsfiddle.net/rGM2t/1/

Running expand function: `Ext.getCmp("west").expand();` will shrink the center in order to make room for west.
How can I dynamically expand west and force him to go over center and not shrink it?
Is there anything like  `Ext.getCmp("west").softExpand();`?

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Border Layout',
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{


            title: 'West Region is collapsible',
            region:'west',

            xtype: 'panel',
            margins: '5 0 0 5',
            width: 200,
            collapsible: true,  
            collapsed : true,
            id: 'west',
            layout: 'fit'
        },{
            title: 'Center Region',
            region: 'center',     
            xtype: 'panel',
            margins: '5 5 0 0'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });


 Ext.getCmp("west").expand();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need west to float. But putting floating elements in a border layout doesnt make much sense. You could use a `Window` component (which is just a customized floating Panel) to float over the center and the west, and then when the window closes you again see your west and center as before.

something like this maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/3bDWU/